# How can I update store value from Storybook control? [Vuejs, Storybook]

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I have a Vue3 component that uses my auth store (Pinia) to determine whether the user is logged in. I would like to create a story where the user can toggle a Storybook boolean control to set the auth state.

What I need is some sort of hook that I can use when the Storybook control is updated by the user in the Storybook UI where I can then perform an action on the auth store to set the user as logged in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Storybook default settings
import { useGlobalStore } from "@/stores/GlobalStore"
import HeaderSmart from "@/lib-components/HeaderSmart"



export default {
    title: "GLOBAL / Header Smart",
    component: HeaderSmart,
}

const mock = {
    secondary: [
        {
            id: "843",
            name: "Locations & Hours",
            to: "/locations",
            classes: "",
            target: "",
        },
        {
            id: "844",
            name: "Ask a Librarian",
            to: "/research-teaching-support/research-help",
            classes: null,
            target: "",
        },
        {
            id: "845",
            name: "My Account",
            to: "https://catalog.library.ucla.edu/vwebv/login;jsessionid=9D14C6523970C30728D965F6BD6B914D",
            classes: null,
            target: "1",
        },
    ],
    primary: [
        {
            id: "835",
            name: "Get help with...",
            to: null,
            classes: "",
            target: "",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "833",
                    name: "Borrowing Books and Equipment",
                    to: "/help/services-resources/borrowing-books-and-equipment",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "840",
                    name: "All Services & Resources",
                    to: "/help/services-resources",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: "834",
            name: "Visit",
            to: "/events-exhibits",
            classes: null,
            target: "",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "841",
                    name: "Locations & Hours",
                    to: "/visit/locations",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "837",
                    name: "Events & Exhibitions",
                    to: "/visit/events-exhibits",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: "836",
            name: "About",
            to: null,
            classes: null,
            target: "",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "842",
                    name: "Library News",
                    to: "/about/news",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "838",
                    name: "Staff Directory",
                    to: "/about/staff",
                    classes: "",
                    target: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: "839",
            name: "Support us",
            to: "https://giving.ucla.edu/Standard/NetDonate.aspx?SiteNum=463",
            classes: null,
            target: "1",
            children: [],
        },
    ],
}

// Variations of stories below
export const Default = () => ({
    created() {
        const globalStore = useGlobalStore()
        globalStore.header.primary = mock.primary
        globalStore.header.secondary = mock.secondary
        globalStore.winWidth = 824
    },

    components: { HeaderSmart },


    template: `<header-smart />`,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by using the created hook of Vue components.

```
import { useAuthStore } from "@src/stores/auth";
import { Meta, Story } from "@storybook/vue3";
import MocNav from "./MocNav.vue";

const auth = useAuthStore();

export default {
  title: "components/MocNav",
  components: { MocNav },
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => ({
  components: { MocNav },
  setup() {
    return { args };
  },
  template: "<MocNav v-bind='args' />",
  created() {
    if (args.authenticated) {
      auth.login(...);
    } else {
      auth.logout();
    }
  },
});

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  authenticated: true,
};
```

The user can now use the Storybook form controls to alter the auth store state.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue if the component has multiple stories though does it? Did you find a way to manipulate the state on a per story basis?

Comment: I eventually got frustrated at the stores not being usable in my tests, so i moved towards a pattern where my components define inject methods instead of performing actions directly on the store. Then components above them then provide the methods that interact with the store. In the test component I just provide different methods that do not require the store and mock some values up. Only the very top layer of my app interacts with store. A lot of my components now have *.container.vue helpers that provide the store access, leaving me to test the component itself in stories easily.